# C:\Users\krish\Desktop\code\hello> docker-compose up can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found

Tags: python, django

When I try to run `docker-compose up`

I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\krish\Desktop\code\hello>docker-compose up can't find a
suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found
```

Here is what the console prompts out:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file should be in the same directory.